# Fixing RegEx Split() function - Empty string as first entry

Tags: c#, .net, regex, split

upfront the code to visualize a bit the problem I am facing:

1. This is the text that needs to be split.

> ```
> :20:0444453880181732
> :21:0444453880131350
> :22:CANCEL/ABCDEF0131835055
> :23:BUY/CALL/E/EUR
> :82A:ABCDEFZZ80A
> :87A:4444655604
> :30:061123
> :31G:070416/1000/USNY
> :31E:070418
> :26F:PRINCIPAL
> :32B:EUR1000000,00
> :36:1,31000000
> :33B:USD1310000,00
> :37K:PCT1,60000000
> :34P:061127USD16000,00
> :57A:ABCDEFZZ80A
> ```

This is my Regex

```
 Regex r = new Regex(@"\:\d{2}\w*\:", RegexOptions.Multiline);

 MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(Content);
 string[] items = r.Split(Content);

 // ----- Fix for first entry being empty string.
 int index = items[0] == string.Empty ? 1 : 0;

 foreach (Match match in matches)
 {
    MessageField field = new MessageField();

    field.FieldIdExtended = match.Value;
    field.Content = items[index];

    Fields.Add(field);

    index++;
 }
```

As you can see from the comments the problem occurs with the splitting of the string.
It returns as first item an empty string. 
Is there any elegant way to solve this?

Thanks, Dimi

Comment: Another way to fix the unwanted empty strings is to use a little LINQ: `string[] items = r.Split(Content).Where(s => !String.IsEmpty(s)).ToArray()`. If the regex is hard to get right this may well be simpler (and thus easier to maintain) rather than tweaking the regex for a single (start of match) special case).

Comment: The problem here is to get also the matching expression in one go together with the match, if it would be only about splitting then of course you are right there are many more options available...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that you are getting this behaviour is that your first delimiter from the split has nothing before it and this the first entry is blank.

The way to solve this properly is probably to capture the value that you want in the regular expression and then just get it from your match set.

At a rough first guess you probably want something like:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^:(?<id>\d{2}\w*):(?<content>.*)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);

MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(Content);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    MessageField field = new MessageField();

    field.FieldIdExtended = match.Groups["id"].ToString()
    field.Content = match.Groups["content"].ToString();

    Fields.Add(field);

}
```

The use of named capture groups makes it easy to extract stuff. You may need to tweak the regex to be more as you want. Currently it gets `20` as id and `0444453880181732` as content. I wasn't 100% clear on what you needed to capture but you look ok with regex so I assume that isn't a problem. :)

Essentially here you are not really trying to split stuff but match stuff and pull it out.

Comment: +1 nice, I was about to post something similar. A couple of things: (1) your last group should refer to "content" not "test", (2) the `:` doesn't need to be escaped (the OP did that too), (3) you should be able to get rid of the `\n` at the end of the regex; if anything use `^` and `$` at the start and end, respectively. (4) I prefer `.Value` to `.ToString()`.

Comment: @AhmadMageed: Thanks. 1 was due to me realising when I pasted the code intot he question that I shouldn't call it test and forgetting to update everywhere. 2 I noticed when reading the question but then C&Ped his regex and modified it and forgot to remove the escaping. 3 is an excellent point and I have now changed it to anchor at both the beginning and end of the line with ^ and $. Thanks for the feedback. :)

Comment: a single correction to your code : 
(?<content>.*) should be (?<content>.\w*) so I have the correct content :) the rest is more than fine & therefore accepted, many thanks!!!

Answer (score -3):

use:

```
string[] items = r.Split(Content, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

to remove empty entries.